# Specific information on how to insert into html table

Tags: php, html, html-table

I am trying to use the results of a database and display them in an HTML table. I've searched around but can't find a specific answer for my situation as I am new to PHP and I had to copy this code from another source because I was unable to get it to work on my own. Please help.

```
<?php $server = "127.0.0.1";
$user = "admin";
$pass = "password";
$dbname = "hysteryalelogs";
// Create connection in mysqli
$connection = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);
//Check connection in mysqli
if($connection->connect_error){
    die("Error on connection:" .$connection->connect_error);
}
//Display the informaion
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logs";
$res = $connection->query($sql);
if($res->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "Sales Number: ". $row["Sales_Number"]. "<br/>";
    echo "Quantity: ". $row["Quantity"]. "<br/>";
    echo "Due Date: ". $row["Due_Date"]. "<br/>";
    echo "Burnished Housing: ". $row["Burnished"]. "<br/>";
    echo "Greased Bearings: ". $row["Grease"]. "<br/>";
    echo "Air Cleaned: ". $row["Air"]. "<br/>";
    echo "SS Screw: ". $row["Screw"]. "<br/>";
    echo "Test Date: ". $row["Test_Date"]. "<br/>";
    echo "Pass: ". $row["Pass"]. "<br/>";
    echo "Fail: ". $row["Fail"]. "<br/>";
    echo "Tester: ". $row["Tester"]. "<br/>";
    echo "Final Check: ". $row["Final_Check"]. "<br/>";
    echo "Green Dot: ". $row["Green_Dot"]. "<br/>";
    echo "Green Dot Check: ". $row["Green_Dot_Check"]. "<br/>";
    echo "Ship Date: ". $row["Ship_Date"]. "<br/>";
    echo "Serial Number: ". $row["Serial_Number"]. "<br><br><hr><br/>";
  }
  } else {
echo "No Record Found!";
}
$connection->close();
?>
```

(clarification) The code works. I Just don't know how to format the table for it to display inside.

Comment: @Brian deserves a medal for this one. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47682841/5

Comment: This is not a newb friendly place. We all expect everyone to do their due diligence in learning how to post and use the site. Its just how things are.

Comment: can only gauss at your format, but you simply echo the appropriate html `echo "<td>Sales Number:</td><td> ". $row["Sales_Number"]. "</td>";`

Answer (score 1):

Hi :) Hope this helps :)

```
<?php 
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$user = "admin";
$pass = "password";
$dbname = "hysteryalelogs";
// Create connection in mysqli
$connection = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);
//Check connection in mysqli
if($connection->connect_error){
die("Error on connection:" .$connection->connect_error);
}
//Display the informaion
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logs";
$res = $connection->query($sql);
if($res->num_rows > 0){
echo "<table border='3px' cellpadding='5px' cellspacing='5px' align='center' bgcolor='skyblue' ";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><center><strong>Sales Number</strong></center></td>";
echo "<td><center><strong>Quantity</strong></center></td>";
echo "<td><center><strong>Due Date</strong></center></td>";
echo "<td><center><strong>Burnished Housing</strong></center></td>";
echo "<td><center><strong>Greased Bearings</strong></center></td>";
echo "<td><center><strong>Air Cleaned</strong></center></td>";
echo "<td><center><strong>SS Screw</strong></center></td>";
echo "<td><center><strong>Test Date</strong></center></td>";
echo "<td><center><strong>Pass</strong></center></td>";
echo "<td><center><strong>Fail</strong></center></td>";
echo "<td><center><strong>Tester</strong></center></td>";
echo "<td><center><strong>Final Check</strong></center></td>";
echo "<td><center><strong>Green Dot</strong></center></td>";
echo "<td><center><strong>Green Dot Check</strong></center></td>";
echo "<td><center><strong>Ship Date</strong></center></td>";
echo "<td><center><strong>Serial Number</strong></center></td>";
echo "</tr>";
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Sales_Number"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Quantity"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Due_Date"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Burnished"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Grease"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Air"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Screw"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Test_Date"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Pass"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Fail"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Tester"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Final_Check"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Green_Dot"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Green_Dot_Check"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Ship_Date"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<center>"."<i>".$row["Serial_Number"]."</i>"."</center>"."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "No Record Found!";
}
$connection->close();
?>
```